# Is it possible to fetch text content into view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are these files

- views/sign_up/new.html.erb
- views/sign_up/content.text.erb

I'd like to show the content of `content.text.erb` in this text_area as default.
How can I?

**views/sign_up/new.html.erb**

```
<%= text_area :page, :content, :readonly => 'true', :size => '250x10' %>
```

**views/sign_up/content.text.erb**

```
Hello

Are you seeing this?


This should be at Line 6.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area), you'd need to set `@page.content` (because of your first two params, `:page` and `:content`). If this is not possible, I'd fall back to a standard "hardcoded" textarea, like `<textarea><%= render file: "sign_up/content" -%></textarea>`

Comment: This was the perfect answer. But How can I put scroll bar? It won't appear even when there are many lines.

Comment: @MKK You could add a style for textarea like `textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}` to enable scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tested it your answer should look about this:

```
<%= text_area :page, :content, :readonly => 'true', :size => '250x10', :value => render_to_string("/sign_up/content") %>
```

You may need to apply `html_safe` on the returned string from `render_to_string`

UPDATE:

After trying myself I got an error so I came up with a workaround:

1 - set @val in your controller the following way:

```
@val = render_to_string(:file => "/sign_up/content.html.erb", :layout => false)
```

2 - Then in your view:

```
<%= text_area :page, :content, :readonly => 'true', :size => '250x10', :value => @val %>
```

Works as charm.

If you don't want to use the value attribute of textarea you can assign the value in step 1 to the `@page.content` and it will automatically be inserted as a default value to the form input.

Comment: A textarea doesn't have a value AFAIK

Comment: According to W3, it hasn't. http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/forms.html#the-textarea-element. "Works on chrome" doesn't mean that it also works in other browsers, that's why there is a standard we should follow ;-)

Comment: @ErezRabih I get this:( undefined method `render_to_string'